# How do I set up a method in which one of the arguments passed might have no value?

Tags: python, methods, return

I apologize in advance, as I'm not even sure myself how to ask this question. I'm basically a self taught programmer, and I'm struggling in a section of my project which requires me to pass information from one method to another, with the possibility that one of the arguments might not have a value in it at all.

The project is a game I'm working on. A sort of two player game that is a very basic pvp/dice rolling combat system. In this game, the player can have certain feats that offer certain bonuses to themselves, or apply certain penalties to the opponent. Once that feat is used, it cannot be used again in that same game, and a feat can only be selected during the player's turn.

For example. The feat 'crippling blow' will apply a -1 penalty to the OPPONENT'S next roll, or the feat 'titan blow' will apply a +50% bonus to the PLAYER'S damage. Because of this, I know I need to make sure that the 'determineHit' method for that player takes in BOTH 'featUsed' functions. For example, if Player One decides to use Crippling blow, that will obviously do nothing for his immediate attack, but will affect Player Two's roll for an attack.

The problem is, feats are selected on the player's turn. So naturally, at the beginning, when playerOne is going, his usedFeat method will be filled out with the appropiate data, but playerTwo's method will have nothing in it.

I have the entire list of feats set up in a JSON. The list is fairly extensive, but I will only place the bits relevant to the example here. As you will see in the JSON, only the name of the feat, and "action" is needed. The name is obviously the name, and the "action" is the numerical value used to manipulate the player's rolls in some fashion.

I have also included the two relevant methods, and any notes that might help.

Feat JSON:

```py
    "titan blow": {
      "stat": "strength",
      "desc": "Your next attack deals 50% more damage, can only be used once per fight.",
      "requirements": [13, 10, 0, 0, "greater crushing blow"],
      "status": "active",
      "action": 0.5
    },
    "crippling blow": {
      "stat": "strength",
      "desc": "You strike your opponent with such a force that it hinders their own attempts to strike back, given them a -1 to their next attack.",
      "requirements": [3, 6, 4, 0, "none", 0],
      "status": "active",
      "action": -1
    },
    "improved crippling blow": {
      "stat": "strength",
      "desc": "improves crippling blow to -3 to their next attack.",
      "requirements": [7, 8, 5, 0, "crippling blow"],
      "status": "active",
      "action": -3
    },
    "greater crippling blow": {
      "stat": "strength",
      "desc": "improves crippling blow to -5 to their next attack.",
      "requirements": [9, 9, 6, 0, "improved crippling blow"],
      "status": "active",
      "action": -5
```

method to ask player for feat intended to be used (Note: featDict is pulled from a module that loads and dumps the feat JSON above. Also Note there is a method called 'pTwoFeatUsed(self)' that is basically this exact code, only for player two):

```py
   def pOneFeatUsed(self):
        featDict = gameFeats.featDict()[0]
        feat = ""
        while feat != "none":
            feat = input("Do you wish to use a feat? (type full name of feat here, or 'none'): ")
            if feat == 'power attack' or feat == 'combat expertise' or feat == 'defensive fighting' or feat == 'masochist':
                print(feat + " is a passive feat, and will be determined after this.")
            elif feat in self.pOneInfo['feats taken']:
                print(featDict[0][feat]['action'])
                return [feat, featDict[0][feat]['action']]
            elif feat not in self.pOneInfo['feats taken'] and feat != "none":
                print("Either you do not have that feat, or you did not type it correctly")
```

Just like featUsed method, there is a 'determineHitPTwo' method that is basically the exact same code, just for playerTwo's attack

```py
   def determineHitPOne(self):
            pOneToHit = self.pOneInfo['hit']
            pTwoAC = self.pTwoInfo['ac']
            for word in self.pOneInfo["feats taken"]:
                if word == "power attack":
                    self.pOnepMod = self.pOnePowerAttack()
                if word == "combat expertise":
                    self.pOnecMod = self.pOneCombatExpertise()
                if word == "defensive fighting":
                    self.pOnedMod = self.pOneDefensiveFighting()
                if word == "masochist":
                    self.pOnemMod = self.pOneMasochist()
            pMod = self.pOnepMod
            cMod = self.pOnecMod
            dMod = self.pOnedMod
            mMod = self.pOnemMod
            pTwodMod = self.pTwodMod
            pTwomMod = self.pTwomMod
            hit = random.randint(1, 20)
            total = int(hit + pOneToHit - pMod + cMod - dMod + mMod)
            print("Roll: " + str(hit) + " Base: " + str(pOneToHit) + " PA: " + str(pMod) + " CE: " + str(cMod) + " DF: " + str(dMod) + " MC: " + str(mMod))
            totalAC = pTwoAC + pTwodMod - pTwomMod
            print("P2 AC: " + str(pTwoAC) + " DF: " + str(pTwodMod) + " MC: " + str(pTwomMod))
            if total >= totalAC:
                print(self.playerOne + " rolled a " + str(total) + " to hit an AC " + str(totalAC) + " and was successful.")
                self.pTwodMod = 0
                self.pTwomMod = 0
                self.determineDamagePOne()
            else:
                print(self.playerTwo + " rolled a " + str(total) + " to hit an AC " + str(totalAC) + " and missed.")
                self.pTwodMod = 0
                self.pTwomMod = 0
                self.scoreboard()
```

I have tried numerous things. I am aware of setting default values for passing in arguments, but this only seems to work for anything BUT lists and dictonaries. I have tried:

```py
   def determineHitPOne(self, pOneFeatUsed = ["none", 0], pTwoFeatUsed = ["none", 0]):
```

to attempt to assign a default list to the variables, but 1) from what I understand, this is bad use, as the data is mutable, and will not offer desired results? and 2) This doesn't even call the methods desired, and if I put in the method 'pOneFeatUsed = self.pOneFeatUsed() it will obviously call the method itself and execute it, rather than assign it's values.

I've tried something called a sentinel:

```py
def determineHitPOne(self, pOneFeatUsed = None, pTwoFeatUsed = None):
    if pOneFeatUsed is None:
        pOneFeatUsed = ["none", 0]
    if pTwoFeatUsed is None:
        pTwoFeatUsed = ["none", 0]
```

But again, I'm not sure how to call the method such that I get the values assigned in it (If there are any), or assign the default ["none", 0] if the player hasn't had a turn yet, and there are no values to assign.

Please request more information if - as I suspect - this explanation is clear as mud. If you need more information, I will be happy to supply it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are on the right track. Your last solution of using default values in arguments makes those arguments optional for the caller. So if you want to call the function to just assign default value, you can simply call `determineHitPOne()` without any arguments. You can have multiple variants of this now as well, I would recommend reading more on python optional arguments for more details (e.g. [here](https://linux.die.net/diveintopython/html/power_of_introspection/optional_arguments.html) and [here](https://treyhunner.com/2018/04/keyword-arguments-in-python/))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you define a method in this way:

```
def determineHitPOne(self, pOneFeatUsed=None, pTwoFeatUsed=None):
```

You are defining `pOneFeatUsed` as a new variable, essentially ignoring the existence of the `pOneFeatUsed` method. This syntax isn't going to call the method that you want, it's going to create a new variable with that name and then either A) assign None to it if you didn't provide a value for that argument or B) assign whatever value you provided.

Instead, you could store the state of the last-used feat from the other play and then check that field.

```
def pOneFeatUsed(self):
    featDict = gameFeats.featDict()[0]
    self.p1_last_feat = None
    while self.p1_last_feat is not None:
       self.p1_last_feat = input("Do you wish to use a feat? (type full name of feat here, or 'none'): ")
        if self.p1_last_feat == 'none':
            self.p1_last_feat = None
        elif self.p1_last_feat in ('power attack', 'combat expertise', 'defensive fighting', 'masochist'):
            print(self.p1_last_feat + " is a passive feat, and will be determined after this.")
        elif self.p1_last_feat in self.pOneInfo['feats taken']:
            print(featDict[0][self.p1_last_feat ]['action'])
            return [self.p1_last_feat , featDict[0][self.p1_last_feat ]['action']]
        else self.p1_last_feat not in self.pOneInfo['feats taken']:
            print("Either you do not have that feat, or you did not type it correctly")
```

Then, instead of trying to call that method again you can just check the state of `last_feat`

```
def determineHitPOne(self):
    if self.p1_last_feat is None:
        pOneFeatUsed = ["none", 0]
    if self.p2_last_feat is None:
        pTwoFeatUsed = ["none", 0]
```

Or you could even store those lists explicitly, if you wanted to. The point is that invoking the method should set an attribute, then you can check the state of that attribute later.

Comment: Would I even need to `return [self.p1_last_feat , featDict[0][self.p1_last_feat ]['action']]` then? the `self.` indicator suggests it's going to be available in the __init__ method? I would probably have to store the 'action' integer in another __init__ variable? I see what this is doing, I'm just confused at why there is a return statement, but it doesn't seem to be used in `determineHitPOne(self)`

Comment: Disregard above statement. I see reasons why it is in there now. To get out of the while loop.

Comment: Those return statements were in your original example. You're correct that you don't have to return those variables, since they're class attributes; you can have the function return whatever you want, including None